# Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.CardView ClassNotFoundException

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, kotlin, android-cardview

I'm trying to inflate a layout that contains a CardView but I'm dealing with some issues.

Bellow is the error being state,

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.hearthstonecards, PID: 14895
    android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v7.widget.CardView" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.hearthstonecards-Kl_z5hCNi7YCycFhods3Tg==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.hearthstonecards-Kl_z5hCNi7YCycFhods3Tg==/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.hearthstonecards-Kl_z5hCNi7YCycFhods3Tg==/split_lib_resources_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.hearthstonecards-Kl_z5hCNi7YCycFhods3Tg==/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.hearthstonecards-Kl_z5hCNi7YCycFhods3Tg==/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.hearthstonecards-Kl_z5hCNi7YCycFhods3Tg==/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.hearthstonecards-Kl_z5hCNi7YCycFhods3Tg==/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.hearthstonecards-Kl_z5hCNi7YCycFhods3Tg==/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.hearthstonecards-Kl_z5hCNi7YCycFhods3Tg==/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.hearthstonecards-Kl_z5hCNi7YCycFhods3Tg==/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.hearthstonecards-Kl_z5hCNi7YCycFhods3Tg==/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.hearthstonecards-Kl_z5hCNi7YCycFhods3Tg==/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.hearthstonecards-Kl_z5hCNi7YCycFhods3Tg==/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.hearthstonecards-Kl_z5hCNi7YCycFhods3Tg==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:606)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:790)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
        at com.example.hearthstonecards.adapter.RecyclerViewAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(RecyclerViewAdapter.kt:34)
        at com.example.hearthstonecards.adapter.RecyclerViewAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(RecyclerViewAdapter.kt:15)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6942)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6114)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5997)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5993)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2227)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1558)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1518)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:613)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:4029)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3746)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:4299)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20672)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6194)
```

Kotlin code within the RecyclerViewAdapter,

```
class RecyclerViewAdapter(private val recyclerViewItems: ArrayList<HearthstoneCardItemData>, context: Context) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewHolder>() {

    private val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context)

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerViewHolder {
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.recycler_view_card_item, parent, false)
        return RecyclerViewHolder(view)
    }
}
```

Below is the xml layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:orientation="vertical">
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/cardView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            card_view:cardCornerRadius="0dp"
            card_view:cardElevation="@dimen/margin10"
            card_view:cardMaxElevation="@dimen/margin10"
            card_view:contentPadding="@dimen/margin10">
        <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_gravity="center">
            <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/iv_card_item"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:tint="@android:color/white"
                    android:padding="5dp"/>
        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

I've also added the right dependencies within the gradle file (i think)

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-alpha02'
implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0-alpha02'
implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
```

I've cleaned  re-build as well, still no change
Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: obviously `android.support.v7.widget.CardView` doesn't come from `androidx`

Comment: Sounds like `androidx` problem. It was moved elsewhere. Try adding the cardview again to the XML without specifying the package, then let it autocomplete the package.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce You're right, `androidx` didn't auto migrate the xml cardview package.

Answer (score 10):

You need `androidx.cardview.widget.CardView` not `android.support.v7.widget.CardView`.

Answer (score 2):

When I migrated to `androidx` my `Android Studio` did not completely migrate. So the point is that if you are migrating to `androidx`, ensure that you add `CardView` dependency to your `build.gradle`

**build.gradle**

```
dependencies {
    // Other dependencies ...
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
}
```

and in your `layout` `xml`

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/info_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Text"/>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 1):

Android studio didn't completely migrate my app to androidx. But after changing the package name within the xml layout fixed the issue.

Thanks everyone!